# Report multiple tests from a single function with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I currently have a simple test which instantiates a bunch of similar objects and executes a method to ensure the method does not throw any exceptions:

```
class TestTemplates(object):

    def test_generate_all(self):
        '''Generate all the templates and ensure none of them throw validation errors'''
        for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('cloudformation.template'):
            object = entry_point.load()
            object().build().to_json()
```

This is reported in the text output of `pytest` as a single test:

```
test/test_templates.py::TestTemplates::test_generate_all PASSED
```

Also in the `junit` XML:

```
<testcase classname="test.test_templates.TestTemplates" file="test/test_templates.py" line="31" name="test_generate_all" time="0.0983951091766"></testcase>
```

Is it possible for each object tested to be reported as a separate test without manually defining a test function for each object?

Comment: I'd generate that list as a fixture, then pass that fixture into a parametrized test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define your list of objects as a fixture, then pass that list to a parametrized test:

```
@pytest.fixture
def entry_point_objects()
    eps = pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('cloudformation.template')
    return [ep.load() for ep in eps]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('obj', entry_point_objects())
def test_generate_all(obj):
    obj().build().to_json()
```

Comment: This gave me exactly the result I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Does it work with `Fixture`? I tried this but only work if `entry_point_objects` is declared as normal Python function

Comment: @CHINTANVADGAMA: (and to others interested) 
Calling fixtures directly (like here) has been removed in Pytest 4.0, so no, the upvoted solution will not work. Like you said, `entry_point_objects` should be a regular function - it's also recommended in the docs (see for example: http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#yield-tests).